# Animation within Interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am confused about the interval dynamics.

I have a six second interval in which I want to run an animation with another animation in callback and a third animation in the callback of the second animation.

Although my animations are ony 800ms plus a 2000ms delay they are not processed within the 6000ms interval and being skipped. What am I missing?

```
var myVar;
var countit;
countit = 1;

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setInterval(slideit, 6000);
}

function slideit() {
    $(".imgcontainer").animate({
        "top": -($(".imgcontainer").height() * countit)
}, 300, function () {
    $(".bannertext").animate({
        opacity: 1,
            "margin-top": "30px",
            "font-size": "2em"
    }, 300, function () {
        $(".bannertext").delay(2000).animate({
            opacity: 0,
                "margin-top": "0px",
                "font-size": "1em"

        }, 200);
    });
});

countit = countit + 1;
if (countit == $(".imgcontainer").length) {
    countit = 0;
}
}

myFunction();
```

### Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1wfd4gdn/7/

Answer (score 0):

No need of callbacks. Jquery animation functions executes in a queue by default. Ref: http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options

```
$(".imgcontainer").animate({
    "top": -($(".imgcontainer").height() * countit)
}, 300)
$(".bannertext").animate({
      opacity: 1,
       "margin-top": "30px",
        "font-size": "2em"
}, 300)
$(".bannertext").delay(2000).animate({
        opacity: 0,
       "margin-top": "0px",
        "font-size": "1em"
 }, 200)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/souravb/1wfd4gdn/8/

Comment: I did that before, the problem was that that when the window was out of focus or minimized, the animation would be out of sync when going back to it so I hoped using callbacks would solve that. But I cannot get it to work.